# How to use the Windows 8 default style (Xaml) in an Outlook plugin

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, outlook

I'm currently creating an Outlook Plugin that has a settings window. The settings window will look like the account setting window in Outlook 2013.

I'm creating this plugin for Outlook on a Windows 8.1 machine.

Now, when you create an Outlook Plugin you can add a form, but this is a Windows Form, which is not good for me. Therefore I've searched on how to create a WPF window for an Outlook Plugin, and basiccly, you choose to add an XAML UserControl, of which the source code will look like:

```
<UserControl x:Class="OutlookAddIn1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now, you can easily create a Window from this by changing `UserControl` to `Window`. Also, you need to inherit from the Base class `Window` in the code behind.

The source will then look like:

```
<Window x:Class="OutlookAddIn1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now, I'll add a button on the WPF Window / UserControl which I've just created.

When you run the application and opens up the just created window, you'll see the following:

[image]

It's working and I see a button, but in order to be consistent, I would like my button, and all the future controls to have the same look as the controls on my native Windows environment (Windows 8.1).

Here's a screenshot from the default Windows Style on Windows 8.1

[image]

As you can see, there's definitely a change between my implementation and the default windows implementation.

So, the question to make it very short: In an Outlook plugin, how do you create your applications so that the style of the controls matches the same style as the Windows controls?

I've searched already a lot on the net, but can't find a solid solution.
It seems that the style in Windows 8 is called Aero2.

I do find a reference to Aero2 in the following locations:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\SystemThemes\Wpf

Here I do find a lot of Xaml files.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF

In here, there's a reference dll named: 'PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll'

Can someome explain me on how I could accomplish this. It would be great because I want my addin to have the same style as the default Windows style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, I've found out that WPF comes with it's own styles that are not linked to Windows at all.

So, the only solution would be to create your own custom controls.

So, I've done that, and here is a very first, very basic version. Which does not relies on input parameters at all.

It was just a demo on how to style a button to have the default Windows 8.1 look:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border x:Name="buttonBaseBorder" BorderBrush="#ACACAC" BorderThickness="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid x:Name="buttonBase" Width="84" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#F0F0F0" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#E5E5E5" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Width="84" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Padding="0" Margin="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  />
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <!-- Set the triggers that are needed for the button. -->
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <!-- Trigger for mouse over on the button. -->
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="buttonBase" Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#ECF4FC" Offset="0.0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#DCECFC" Offset="1.0" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Setter TargetName="buttonBaseBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#7EB4EA" />
        </Trigger>

        <!-- Trigger for when the button is the default one. -->
        <Trigger Property="IsDefault" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="buttonBaseBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#3399FF" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```